# wpf catching mouse down outside my custom control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I'm building a custom control in WPF. I want to catch a mouse down event when my control is in focus but the user clicks outside the control. Is there a way to do that and if so how?

My control inherits from ListBox.

Comment: If the control has focus and any clicks outside don't change that focus, then how does your control loose focus?

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`UIElement.CaptureMouse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse.aspx) and it's partner [`UIElement.ReleaseMouseCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.releasemousecapture.aspx) to capture all mouse events to a single control, regardless of what the mouse was over when the event occurred.

In your example I would capture the mouse when the control has focus, and release the mouse when the control looses focus.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `Window` with a `TextBox` on it.

By registering to `Window`'s `MouseDown` event,

```
MouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(Window_MouseDown);
```

You can use following code

```
private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.IsFocused)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("TextBox1 in focus.");
    }
}
```

To catch this event if `TextBox1` is in focus.